# Color interpolation/smoothing in discrete-colored height map

Tags: image-processing, 3d, gaussian, heightmap, laplacian

I am currently trying to smooth a height-map of a 2D world. I have multiple images of different 2D worlds, so it's something I'm not going to do manually but rather create a script.

Sample of a heightmap:

[image: Height-map]

As you can see, colors do not blend. I'm looking to blend every space to the color of their neighbours so the slope of the height map is **smooth**.

**What have I tried?**

- Applying a blur filter, but it's not enough and gives bad quality results.
- Applying small noise filters but it's not even close to what I need.

**So far...**

Here is what happens if I apply the height-map as it is without interpolating the color with it's neighbours.

[image]

The **result** is flat surfaces, **instead of slopes/mountain**. Hope to make my goal clear.

I believe that interpolating the heights with their neighbours and adding random noise on the surfaces will result in a good quality height-map.

I appreciate your help.

**Bonus**

Do you have any idea how would I create a simulated normal map from the result of this smooth height-map?

Comment: You said you tried with a blur filter, have you also tried with ImageMagick? Something like `convert heightmap.jpg -blur 0x6  heightmap_blurred.png`. See https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/blur/#blur_args.

Comment: @dms I’m trying a better approach I found with CImg and scaling images with interpolation option. Still tweaking the settings to achieve the best result. Will post my answer as soon as I have it well revised.

Answer (score 1):

You could try resizing your image down and then back up again to take advantage of interpolation, e.g. for 5% of original size:

```
magick U0kEbl.png.jpeg -set option:geom "%G" -resize "5%" -resize '%[geom]!' result.png
```

Here are results for 3%, 5% and 8% of original size:

[image]